# autofocus on page load and focus through script not working for textfield

Tags: javascript

I have 3 elements visible to the user:

- 1 Paragraph
- 1 numeric input field takes only numbers
- 1 button

The paragraph displays a random word
The user has to enter the no. of alphabets the word contains and then press enter button from keyboard.

On pressing enter button:

- the result is checked for correctness and corresponding increments are done
- the previous value of the text field should be cleared
- the element displayed in last question should be removed from array (I used splice() method)
- new random word from array has to be displayed to user by setting text of paragraph element
- focus has to be shifted to text field for user entry without the need to use mouse
- on pressing enter button process goes repeating for next word

this process repetition goes on till array becomes empty

in my code everything is working fine, but

- autofocus on web page load
- textfield content clearance and focus shift after enter button press

these are not working kindly help me.

The content is getting cleared only when focus comes manually through mouse click on textfield …..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>



  <p id="Question">Sample question </p>

  <input type="number" onfocus="this.value=''" id="myInputResult" tabindex=1 autofocus>
  <br><br>
  <button id="myBtn1" onclick="myFunction()" tabindex=2>Next</button>
  <br><br>
  <p id="trials"></p>
  <p id="correct"></p>
  <p id="wrong"></p>

  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("myInputResult");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("myBtn1").click();
      }
    });
    var trial_count = 0;
    var correct = 0;
    var wrong = 0;
    var arr1 = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];


    function myFunction() {

      if (arr1.length > 0) {
        // 
        myFunctionSetDemo5(Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length)); // calls function & sends a random integer from 0 to (arr1.length -1)

        //
        document.getElementById("trials").innerHTML = " Trials count : " + trial_count;
        getFocus();
      } else {
        alert("No questions left. Start fresh session ");
        getFocus();
      }

      document.getElementById('myInputResult').value = "";
    }

    function myFunctionSetDemo5(p1) {
      var a = arr1[p1];
      trial_count++;
      document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = "How many alphabets does this word contaion : " + a;

      var entered_result = document.getElementById("myInputResult").value;
      var actual_result = a.length;
      count(actual_result, entered_result);

      arr1.splice(p1, 1);
    }

    function getFocus() {
      document.getElementById('myInputResult').value = "";
      document.getElementById("myInputResult").focus();

      document.getElementById("myInputResult").scrollIntoView();
      //alert("hello");
    }

    function count(a, e) {
      if (a == e) {
        correct++;
      } else {
        wrong++;
      }

      trial_count++;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: now its working .....

Comment: but the trials count is incremented by 2 instead of 1. i dont know if its problem of editor or browser

Comment: all bad experiences one after the other